Analytic expression of the $n$-th derivative of a function of two variables
I am hoping to get Mathematica to find an analytic form for the $n$th derivative of the following function of two variables:
$$f(a,b)=\frac{1}{\left((1-a) b\right)^{-k} \left(1-(1-a) b\right)^{k-n}+\left((1-a) b+a\right)^{-k} \left(1-(1-a) b-a\right)^{k-n}}$$
where $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, $(k,n)\in\mathbb{N}^2$ are two constants such that $k\le n$, and $f(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}$.
To be more specific, rather than an "$n$th derivative", I am really talking about the $\ell$th and $m$th derivative with respect to a and b, as shown in the following Mathematica code:
f[a_, b_] := 1/(
  1/(((1 - a) b)^k (1 - (1 - a) b)^(n - k)) + 
   1/(((1 - a) b + a)^k (1 - (1 - a) b - a)^(n - k)));
D[f[a, b], {a, l}, {b, m}]

The above code produces the following result (which I am including as a screenshot because I have not been able to make the output readable here in any other format):

As far as I can tell, the work done by Mathematica here is unsatisfactory because it still keeps two derivatives, one over $b$ and then one over $a$ (and I cannot understand why it has done the other "simplifications" since, as far as I can tell, they do not really push the ball forward).
This question was spawned following a comment on this other question. The answer to that question uses a workaround for obtaining the result of the nth derivative of a function of one variable. That said, it is unclear to me if or how the proposed method would be transferable to a function of two variables.
This is related to yet another question in which it turns out that Mathematica is (in its current version) capable of producing a satisfactory answer using the DifferenceRoot function (although it is still not clear to me how a potential DifferenceRoot function, if it were to appear in my case, would be used). In this post, Maple was also used, and I have tried that route as well, to no avail in my case.

f[a_, b_] :=    1/(1/(((1 - a) b)^k (1 - (1 - a) b)^(n - k)) +       1/(((1 - a) b + a)^k (1 - (1 - a) b - a)^(n - k))); k = 3; n = 7; l = 5; m = 7; D[f[a, b], {a, l}, {b, m}] result in the output which takes  20.2 MB. Are  you really interested in it?

NO hope to compute n-th derivative for general parameters k and n of function f[a,b] , because is too complex.
This is one of those questions that will remain unanswered for many years, probably.
I may be wrong :P

@user64494 thanks for that test, though I do not think that the fact that Mathematica has a large finite series for specific values is related to the size or existence of the closed form, e.g. Sum[Binomial[n, k] x^k, {k, 0, [Infinity]}] vs Sum[Binomial[n, k] x^k, {k, 0, 17}]. I could be wrong, but I have seen simplifications (for series in particular) not immediately visible to MMA.

@MariuszIwaniuk you might be right, but without asking I would just be stuck on this problem on my own :) thanks for your feedback, I was hoping your workaround would be applicable in this case.
